# Cygwin sshd use cmd instead of bash upon login via PuTTY

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, cmd

I've *finally* got to the point where I can successfully SSH into my server, but commands like 'rake' and 'bundle' don't work! I'd rather be taken to cmd than bash upon login. Is there a command I can put into PuTTY's "Remote Command" box so that cmd gets loaded? I tried "-c cmd" but it just closes upon a successful connection. If I leave it out and just type 'cmd' when the bash prompt is ready it works ok. Also another thing of note is that user environment variables in Windows don't get transferred to the SSH session (like GIT_SSH).

Comment: try `ssh user@host cmd` instead of `ssh user@host -c cmd`?

Comment: That's...exactly what I said I tried. It closes the connection immediately. I've noticed it does that when I execute windows batch files which have an EXIT at the end. So it's like it's running CMD, but CMD exists because it has nothing to do? I don't know.

Comment: Try `path/to/current/dir> call myscript.bat` instead of `path/to/current/dir> myscript.bat` .

Comment: Typing in "cmd /K" opens the command prompt but before it, it shows errors in bash like "$'\r': command not found"

Comment: ^^ google about line endings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing was working, but I came across something which sort of made sense when browsing the passwd file for another problem I was having. The last part of the line indicates what is executed upon login. Originally it was /bin/bash, so I changed it to the cmd executable and it works now.

ex)

```
Administrator:unused:[SID-STUFF]:U-POS-SERVER\Administrator,[SID-HERE]:/cygdrive/c/Users/Administrator:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/cmd
```